# Refresh CSS Bookmarklet that works on latest Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, livereload

Im developing a site and I would like the page to refresh when a change is detected to a CSS file. I used to be able to do this easily with the following bookmarks, but now none of them work on Chrome.

http://david.dojotoolkit.org/recss.html

http://calvincorreli.com/2006/02/13/re-recss/

http://www.paulirish.com/2008/how-to-iterate-quickly-when-debugging-css/

I cant change the HTML of the site im working on so I cant use the livereload app. Ideally I would keep using Chrome but I would switch to another browser if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two ways:

1. Edit css file and use [`livereload`](http://livereload.com) to reload it automatically in Chrome
2. Change your CSS in Chrome and save it (without IDE using).

**About livereload(it works not for css only).**

Use [`livereload`](http://livereload.com). You need download `Livereload 2` and add javascript file to your page or use [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei).

This script is meant to be included into the web pages you want to monitor, like this:

```
<script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

`LiveReload 2` server listens on port 35729 and serves livereload.js over HTTP (besides speaking the web socket protocol on the same port).

A slightly smarter way is to use the host name of the current page, assuming that it is being served from the same computer. This approach enables LiveReload when viewing the web page from other devices on the network:

```
<script>document.write('<script src="http://'
    + location.host.split(':')[0]
    + ':35729/livereload.js"></'
    + 'script>')</script>
```

However, location.host is empty for file: URLs, so we need to account for that:

```
<script>document.write('<script src="http://'
    + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0]
    + ':35729/livereload.js"></'
    + 'script>')</script>
```

LiveReload.js finds a script tag that includes `.../livereload.js` and uses it to determine the hostname/port to connect to. It also understands some options from the query string: host, port, snipver, mindelay and maxdelay.

From [GitHub](https://github.com/livereload/livereload-js)

**About changing CSS in Chrome devtools.**

Just take a minuit and watch a [demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qy5obNItQiQ) from Paul Irish

Comment: As I specified in my question I cant change the HTML of my site. By this I mean javascript tags as well as the page content. Live reload doenst seem to work within these constraints.

Comment: Add javascript file from console...Or change CSS in Chrome devtools

Comment: If I have to manually add the javascript file in the console on each new page then this will undo the time saving of having the CSS refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can fit your needs, since I don't know what editor you use there is two nice ones with embed live editing, are: [Brackets IO](http://brackets.io/) (free) and [JetBrains WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/). If you dont ever want to change editors, like Pinal said, Livereload it's a good one, but sometimes its litte bug to make it, but it's a good choice!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Code Kit https://incident57.com/codekit/ and get the free trial and use it for 10 days or you can buy it for $29, I think its totally worth it. You can use Fire.app also http://fireapp.kkbox.com/. Tincr is also a nice app you can use and I think this one is free http://tin.cr/. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any errors in chrome console? all 3 bookmarklets work fine for me on chrome 35.0.1916.153.

The change might come from your sites server, e.g some servers block requests with additional parameters. In that case you'll need to modify bookmarklet to not add it.